# How to run $curl in xampp shell?

Tags: php, json, shell, curl, omnipay

There is a plugin that need to config the composer

First , I need to run:

https://github.com/thephpleague/omnipay

```
composer require omnipay/paypal:~2.0
```

So, I have type in the above command in xampp shell, it works, and a composer.json , vendor folder is created in xampp root folder.

The first step is success. Second, I need to config

https://github.com/lokielse/omnipay-alipay

I have edit the composer.json to :

```
{
    "require": {
        "lokielse/omnipay-alipay": "dev-master"
    }
}
```

But the problem is it seems I can not run the below command in xampp shell. It just show $ is not a command. So, how can I execute it? Thanks a lot

```
$ curl -s http://getcomposer.org/installer | php
$ php composer.phar update
```

Comment: Security problem "http://..". Use "https://..." instead. In combination with payment stuff.. really dangerous. You would never be able to detect malware in your code, especially in phar files.

Comment: $ here is just the shell prompt and not a part of the command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the first command is working successfully, then it means that your composer works fine by using the command `composer` which usually is a simplification of `php composer.phar`. Also the commands `curl -s http://getcomposer.org/installer | php` are needed to install composer but you clearly have it already installed.

Summarising, **do not run** these commands:

```
curl -s http://getcomposer.org/installer | php
php composer.phar update
```

**Instead run** this:

```
composer update
```

Comment: Please do not advice to install a package installer through unencrypted and untrusted source.

Answer (score 2):

You just have a typo! You dont need to enter $ in your console

Run one of those commands
`composer update` or `php composer.phar update` (depends how you installed composer)